# relation OR instead of AND - Filtered term ID's in loop

Tags: wp-query, functions, loop, filters, taxonomy

Question not related anymore..

First I tought about the relation OR/ AND for results, but I believe I should work with 'operator' => 'NOT IN'. I would like to query the results that meet multiple taxonomies instead of displaying all results that meet 1 of the tax. **New question has been made.**

```
<?php 
function page_content($filters, $is_search = false,  $pg = 1, $cat = -1, $post_type) {

if (!$is_search) {
$filters = explode(',', $filters);
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'paged'          => $pg 
);

$terms = array();
foreach ($filters as $f) {
    if (!empty($f) && is_numeric($f) && $f > 0) {
    $terms[] = $f;
}}

if (!empty($terms)) {
            if (!is_array($query_args['tax_query'])) $query_args['tax_query'] = array();
            $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
'relation' => 'OR', // NOT WORKING, STILL SHOWS 'AND' RESULTS
array(
                'taxonomy' => $post_type . '_filters',
                'terms'    => $terms,
                'field'    => 'id',         
            ));
        }

$queried_items = new WP_Query($query_args);
} else {
global $wp_query;
$queried_items = $wp_query;
}

foreach ($queried_items->posts as $p) {
$taxonomy = str_replace('%#%', $p->post_type, '%#%_filters');
$p->taxonomy = array();
$pfields = array("fields" => "all");
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($p->ID, $taxonomy, $pfields);
$assgined_terms = array();
if ($terms && is_array($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
if (!in_array($term->parent, $assgined_terms)) {
    $p->taxonomy[] = $term;
    array_push($assgined_terms, $term->parent);
}}  }
}}
```

Comment: `relation` is a **`tax_query`** arg, *not* a top-level arg. Please ensure that your tax query is constructed properly - including correct placement of the `relationship` arg - and then report back whether or not it is working.

Comment: You mean the relation should be within the tax query? Tried that and didn't respond. Altough I also thought this should work.

Comment: "*Tried that and didn't respond*" - please **edit your question** to include the code that you tried, and describe the exact outcome of that attempt.

Comment: @SailesHardt I think part of your problem is that you only got one inner array with many terms, try instead one inner array for each term. Using AND/OR on a single inner array has no meaning.

Comment: So you guys are telling me it can be done right? Cannot get this working with an array that meets all taxonomies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Codex:

> relation (string) - The logical relationship between each inner
>   taxonomy array when there is more than one. Possible values are 'AND',
>   'OR'. Do not use with a single inner taxonomy array.

So you are on the right track, but your `tax_query` is wrong.  `relation` is part of the outer `tax_query` array and not part of the top level query arguments.

```
$query_args['tax_query'] = array(
  'relation' => 'OR', 
  array(
    'taxonomy' => $post_type . '_filters',
    'terms'    => $terms,
    'field'    => 'id', 
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanx, I believe this is the answer I was looking for. Accapt that the results are still showing up as if it has one of the taxonomies (AND) instead of having multiple (OR).

Comment: @SailesHardt As stated on your other question: Look at the source in detail. You have to specify an `array( 'relation', array( /* arguments */ ) )` and not a flat array.

Comment: Thanx for helping kaiser. I don't get it :(, didn't I specify it with OR and arguments as s_ha_dum said?